# Is it possible I have a compatibility/config problem with mongoose 7.0.4 reference system

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, post

I'm trying to complete Dave Grey's MERN stack code along and ran in the following issue :

My POST request is stuck on the "Note.create" line and I didn't receive a response. Try catch block doesn't throw any errors.

```
//POST Method
const createNewNote = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { user, title, text } = req.body

    // Confirm data
    if (!user || !title || !text) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'All fields are required' })
    }
    console.log("Data Confirmed")

    // Check for duplicate title
    const duplicate = await Note.findOne({ title }).lean().exec()

    if (duplicate) {
        return res.status(409).json({ message: 'Duplicate note title' })
    }
    console.log("No duplicates")

    // Create and store the new note
    console.log("Starting creation")
        
        const useruser = await User.findById(user).exec()
        console.log(useruser)
        
        const noteObject = {"user" : useruser._id, title, text}
        const note = await Note.create(noteObject)
 
    
    console.log("End of Note.create")
    if (note) { // Created 
        return res.status(201).json({ message: 'New note created' })
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid note data received' })
    }

})
```

These are my schemas for User and Note, respectively:

```
//USER Schema
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    roles: [{
        type: String,
        default: "Employee"
    }],
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

--------------------------------------------------------
//NOTE Schema
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose)

const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User',
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        text: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        completed: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
)

noteSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {
    inc_field: 'ticket',
    id: 'ticketNums',
    start_seq: 500
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema)
```

My console logs until this :

```
POST /notes Data Confirmed No duplicates Starting creation
{
  _id: new ObjectId("64440dcbf47f80931a244dd2"),
  username: 'DanD',
  password:'$2b$10$R7cbeKxN4d8wSNLtShZ4
  MOcwaNfdMApAdYDwYsVA2ofAfcU 
  kju0fm',
  roles: [ 'Admin', 'Owner', 'Manager' ],
  active: true,
  __v: 0
}
```

This user id is in my mongodb database, yet I cannot create a note with the associated user. I tried to google similar issues, or go back and forth with chatGPT, to no avail.

Thank you for your time!

The repo is public on github but doesn't work: https://github.com/gitdagray/mern_stack_course/blob/main/lesson_04/controllers/notesController.js

I tried to send different types of payload to the endpoint and going the `._id` way to get the id directly from the object I'm trying to reference, no luck there.

This is my json payload, I'm using Postman :

```
{
    "user": "64440dcbf47f80931a244dd2",
    "title": "Mrs. Smith's Computer",
    "text": "SSD is down"
}
```

Comment: Why did you add this line `const useruser = await User.findById(user).exec()
        console.log(useruser)` ?

Comment: I wanted to get a bit of insight on what was going on, even creating the note directly this way : "const note = await Note.create({ user, title, text })" doesn't work, my request stays pending forever

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `noteSchema`, You have used `user`

```
const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User',
        },
    }
    //...
)
```

So, should be replace by

```
const noteObject = {user, title, text}
const note = await Note.create(noteObject)
```

because it doesn't consist in `noteSchema` and `useruser` can't create the `_id` property. Here, `Note.create()` will create  notes only by knowing its schema keys like you used `user`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it is indeed a mistake on my paart, unfortunately it doen't fix the issue. I now realize that if I put a ref id of 1 I get an error message like " Unable to cast to ObjectId" but if I change 1 letter on a real reference id, the request stays pending again forever